# Use Spanish ONLY in LibreOffice

Tags: libreoffice, language-support

I tried to use Spanish in LibreOffice, but it won't work.

The Spain Language Pack is installed. If I enable it, my complete Ubuntu installation is in Spanish, but not in LibreOffice.

I tried to use Spanish via LibreOffice extension, but Spanish is nowhere to be found.

Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you mean you want to use LibreOffice's Spanish-language user interface, and enable its editing features for Spanish (e.g. spell-checking).

1. Make sure the language packages are installed. To do this, open the Language Support dialog (from the menu or by running `gnome-language-selector`), click "Install / Remove Languages...", make sure the box for "Spanish; Castilian" is ticked:

   [image: Install Spanish language pack]

   Then, if needed, press "Apply Changes".

   *Don't* change the order of the languages (i.e. leave English on top) in the main Language Support dialog; this means that the default language for all applications will be English.

   After doing this, make sure the packages `libreoffice-l10-es` (Spanish UI), `libreoffice-help-es` (if you need the help in Spanish), and a Spanish spelling dictionary are installed. (I'm not sure whether Language Support dialog installs these for you.)
2. Open any LibreOffice application, and browse to Tools > Options > Language Settings > Languages:

   [image: LO language options]
3. Change "User interface", "Locale setting", "Default currency", and default document language (as desired) to your desired national variety of Spanish, and press OK. (You must close and reopen LibreOffice before the language will change.)

   This will change the language only for LibreOffice, leaving other applications in English.

   If you meant you want the Spanish-language tools (for writing documents in Spanish) but still want the English UI, do the same, but leave "User interface" as English.

Comment: okay, this works...and how I can set that the first "!"(or"?") is a "¡" instead of a "!"?

Answer (score 0):

Is the `libreoffice-l10n-es` package installed? It will need to be installed for LibreOffice to have Spanish UI. You will also need `libreoffice-help-es` for getting the documentation in Spanish.